# Passive present simple instead of passive present perfect

Tags: present-perfect, passive-voice, present-simple

> (1) It is reported that he was present at the crime scene.

> (2) It has been reported that he was present at the crime scene.

I am sure that the second sentence is correct. Is the first one grammatically correct? If yes, how these two sentences differ in meaning?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, both sentences are grammatically valid.
2. On one level, there could be a slight difference in implication. [The present passive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165693/the-difference-in-meaning-between-present-simple-passive-and-present-perfect-pas) puts an emphasis on, well, the present, while the perfect emphasizes how the present *got to be this way* (via actions in the past).
3. Except that's not so important in this example. For an example like "the bed is made," making a bed is not a process that continues indefinitely. However, "it is reported" is an idiomatic, indirect way of talking about represented speech that doesn't necessarily make strong implications about *when* it was reported, much like "Some say that..." Obviously we're not discussing the future, so in these uses ("some say," "it is rumored that," "it is understood that"), there is little practical difference between the present and the past.

Comment: At the end of your third point you have said: "there is little practical difference between the present and the past". Since my question is about present and present perfect, I became confused. Did you mean there is little practical difference between the present and the present perfect?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I mean, since the present perfect involves the past: it speaks of “a past event that has present consequences.” In this case, the “reporting” is such a vague event that there’s no implication about when it happened or how long it lasted.

Comment: Also note that "it is reported" is pretty rare.  You would more likely hear "it is being reported" or "it is now being reported" from a TV news anchor to introduce information that is currently coming in or has just recently come in.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is grammatically correct. The present can be used for things that occurred in the recent or indefinite past, that are still true.

However, in this particular case, I think the second sentence is less awkward and thus better.

I think it might be further improved by being rephrased in he active voice. Sometimes the passive voice is actually better than the active, and often it is just as good, but in some cases the active is better. Options here would include:

> - A witness reported that he was present at the crime scene.
> - John Smith said that he was present at the crime scene.

Unless, of course, the intention is not to disclose who reported his presence at the crime scene, in which case the passive voice is exactly the tool to use.